# Removing the #1 house from the screen of Lenovo Thinkpad

Tags: windows-7, laptop, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad (W541).

One my screen at all times is the #1 House icon.

How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: First step in identify what software, is doing this, is to confirm if it does or does not happen in a minimalist boot configuration.

Comment: I suspect based on my research, you have an application called Pokki installed, you should remove it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's the Lenovo on-screen indicator for your Numlock key.

To get rid of it, right-click your desktop and head to Screen resolution > Advanced settings > On Screen display.

Then change the "indicator settings" from "Always show the indicator" to "Show the indicator for a few seconds".

[image]

Comment: My [research](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/missing-house-icon-from-desktop-taskbar-in-81/111d3ce6-3501-4380-bd16-640ed0631327?page=1) indicates its actually an icon generated by Pokki

Comment: @Ramhound We have many Lenovo laptops around here, it looks like the same indicator they use (to me anyway), and the OP says it's a Lenovo, so I'm going to stick with the thinking that's it's the Lenovo OSD utility. Perhaps Lenovo bought it form Pokki or whomever. ;)

Comment: [Lenovo by default installed Pokki on all Windows 8 devices they sold.](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2047233/lenono-plans-to-install-pokkis-start-menu-replacement-and-app-store-on-pcs.html).  I realize the question has a Windows 7 tag, but I have learned, not to take tags as an actual indication of anything.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think it's related to that Pokki start menu replacement stuff, as that lock key indicator predates Windows 8 -- it's on our Win 7 Lenovos. But who knows, we'll have to wait for the OP to confirm it (or not). :)

Comment: @Ramhound It has nothing to do with Pokki at all. It's an app called "Lenovo On Screen Display" that is part of the "[Lenovo Hotkey Features Integration](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/ThinkPad-T-Series-laptops/ThinkPad-T530/downloads/DS029026)" software package. (While that link is for the Windows 10 version, the software is available for Windows 7, 8, and 10.)

Comment: Somebody already pointed that out last week...